# How to properly use nullable analysis attributes for a method that validates an object properties

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a class with some properties which are nullable. I have a Validate method which checks the properties and if they are null will throw exception. However, after calling the validate method, I am still getting the possible null warning. Here is an example:

```
    public class CosmosDbOptions
    {
        public string? DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public string? InitialContainerName { get; set; }
#pragma warning disable CA1056 // URI-like properties should not be strings
        public string? EndpointUrl { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CA1056 // URI-like properties should not be strings
        public string? AuthorizationKey { get; set; }
        public string? AzureADTenantId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? Timeout { get; set; }

        public AuthenticationMode AuthenticationMode => GetAuthenticationMode();
        public string? KeyVaultKeyName { get; private set; }

        private AuthenticationMode GetAuthenticationMode()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AzureADTenantId))
            {
                return AuthenticationMode.AzureActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(KeyVaultKeyName))
            {
                return AuthenticationMode.AuhtorizationKeyFromKeyVault;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AuthorizationKey))
            {
                return AuthenticationMode.AuthorizationKey;
            }

            return AuthenticationMode.None;
        }

        public void Validate()
        {
            _ = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatabaseName) ? DatabaseName : throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(DatabaseName));
            _ = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InitialContainerName) ? InitialContainerName : throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(InitialContainerName));
            _ = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EndpointUrl) ? EndpointUrl : throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(EndpointUrl));

            if (AuthenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.None)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Authentication mode for accessing CosmosDb is not valid!");
            }

            if (AuthenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.AuthorizationKey)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AuthorizationKey))
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(AuthorizationKey));
                }
            }

            if (AuthenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.AzureActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AzureADTenantId))
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(AzureADTenantId));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public enum AuthenticationMode
    {
        AuthorizationKey,
        AuhtorizationKeyFromKeyVault,
        AzureActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity,
        None
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void DoSomeAction(CosmosDbOptions options)
        {
            _ = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
            options.Validate();
            string x = options.DatabaseName; // here I still get the warning
            
            if (options.AuthenticationMode == AuthenticationMode.AuthorizationKey)
            {
                string y = options.AuthorizationKey; // or here I get warning
            }
        }
    }
```

I read this [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis), however I could not resolve the issue using any of the mentioned attributes. Off course I could use null-forgiving-operator but that's not my preference

Comment: You could have `Validate` return something with non-nullable values to use instead.  Otherwise I don't think there's a way to specify that if an instance method returns then certain properties of the class are not null.

Comment: I decorated the validate method with " [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(DatabaseName))]" and changed the return type to bool and put "return true" as the last line of method. However now I am getting another warning. "Member 'DatabaseName' must have a non-null value when exiting with 'true'"

Comment: I believe `MemberNotNullWhen` is for when you have helper methods that set field/properties that are called from the constructor to handle the CS8618 warning about non-nullable properties/fields not being set.  It does not pertain to calling an instance method after the instance of the object is created to indicate that the nullable properties are actually not null.

Comment: You can either just use the null forgiving operator `!` after the properties after you call your `Validate` method because you know they are not null, or create a class like `ValidCosmosDbOptions` where the properties are not nullable and have `Validate` return that with the values copied in.

Comment: For which properties are you still getting null warnings?

Comment: @juharr I'm afraid it's not possible to make another class with non nullable properties, since based on the authentication mode, some of them should be null or empty

Comment: @AndrewH for all of them

Comment: @user3638006 Then you need to use the null-forgiving operator, as suggested. This is the exact use case for such an operator. I don't know the details and limitations of the null safety changes as it pertains to the Roslyn analyzer, but that should fix the warnings if/until the limitation is addressed. This may be a good issue to post on the Roslyn Github issues for more direct assistance from the Roslyn team/community.

Comment: @AndrewH Thanks, I filed an issue here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/56800